# How to write Update with join in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to run this SQL to update a table.  The issue is that I need a join in order to update the correct record.  This is what I have come up with so far:

```
Update UserProfile 
  set UserProfile.PropertyValue = 'Test'
  join ProfilePropertyDefinition
      on ProfilePropertyDefinition.Id = UserProfile.PropertyDefinitionId
  where UserProfile.UserId = 11
  and ProfilePropertyDefinition.PortalID = 0
  and ProfilePropertyDefinition.PropertyName = 'Address1'
  and ProfilePropertyDefinition.PropertyCategory = 'Address'
```

This is the message I get:

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'join'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, you forgot the `from` clause:

```
Update UserProfile 
  set UserProfile.PropertyValue = 'Test'
  from UserProfile
  join ProfilePropertyDefinition
      on ProfilePropertyDefinition.Id = UserProfile.PropertyDefinitionId
  where UserProfile.UserId = 11
  and ProfilePropertyDefinition.PortalID = 0
  and ProfilePropertyDefinition.PropertyName = 'Address1'
  and ProfilePropertyDefinition.PropertyCategory = 'Address'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Update UserProfile 
  set UserProfile.PropertyValue = 'Test'
from UserProfile
  join ProfilePropertyDefinition
      on ProfilePropertyDefinition.Id = UserProfile.PropertyDefinitionId
  where UserProfile.UserId = 11
  and ProfilePropertyDefinition.PortalID = 0
  and ProfilePropertyDefinition.PropertyName = 'Address1'
  and ProfilePropertyDefinition.PropertyCategory = 'Address'
```

You have to repeat the table to update in the `from` clause - even iof this syntax looks a little strange.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a FROM clause:

```
Update a 
set    PropertyValue = 'Test'
FROM   UserProfile as a 
       inner join ProfilePropertyDefinition as b
       on b.Id = a.PropertyDefinitionId
where  a.UserId = 11
       and b.PortalID = 0
       and b.PropertyName = 'Address1'
       and b.PropertyCategory = 'Address';
```